# Shopware 6.5 line-item with customfields

Tags: shopware, shopware6

is there a way to get access to the custom fields in twig in the shopping cart in shopware 6.5? In Shopware 6.4 I could do this with lineItem.payload.customFields now in Shopware 6.5 this is empty. I can't find this under {{dump(lineItem)}}

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
Coming with `6.5.1.0` there will be the possibility to [make custom fields exposed](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/e457dd99e8829bd8587808d59284ab9f6f2778fc) in carts again. This is a setting in the custom field configuration and it can be set when creating the custom field in an app/plugin or via the administration.

---

You now have to [create a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) and subscribe to `CartBeforeSerializationEvent` to add allowed custom fields for exposition in the cart.

```php
class CartBeforeSerializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CartBeforeSerializationEvent::class => 'onCartBeforeSerialization',
        ];
    }

    public function onCartBeforeSerialization(CartBeforeSerializationEvent $event): void
    {
        $allowed = $event->getCustomFieldAllowList();
        $allowed[] = 'my_custom_field';
        
        $event->setCustomFieldAllowList($allowed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there also a solution for Shopware apps?

Comment: Currently not. Keep in mind this is a release candidate. This will most likely change until the final release. A solution is in the making.

Comment: Ok thanks. Have you tested your code? Unfortunately this does not work for me in RC3. Otherwise I have to wait until the final version and can then adapt the apps

Comment: Yes it does work. You can convince yourself by having a look at [`CartSerializationCleaner`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5f506d31ff6478f72efc26c3da35cb04ced70a7a/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/CartSerializationCleaner.php#L31). As stated there is a solution for apps in the making but it will likely arrive with the first minor release, that would be `6.5.0.1`. Usually there is a minor release soon after an initial major release, so it won't be much longer.

Comment: I have now installed version 6.5.1.0 but the field customfields in the shopping cart is still empty. Is it wanted like that?

Comment: found the solution. allow-cart-expose must be activated in the manifest.